# Primary VS. Logical Types When Using Manual Partitioning At Ubuntu Installation

Tags: 14.04, partitioning, system-installation, hard-drive, boot-partition

I am very new to Ubuntu, and I apologize beforehand if my terminology is incorrect.  I'm constantly learning new things with all of this! I am working with Ubuntu 14.04 (I believe.) LTS.

I read very thorough instructions for using manual partitioning at Ubuntu installation titled: "How to Use Manual Partitioning During Installation?" Although I found this extremely helpful (even the additional comments), I am still confused about part of this process.

In the steps for using manual partitioning on a clean disk, it was recommended to assign the "/" root fs as logical.  However, at the end of the instructions, it was suggested that for MBR scheme disks "/" root fs be assigned as primary.

The computer I am working on did, at one point, have an MBR partition set-up on it.  However, after several mishaps, the partitions that were automatically placed, were wiped out.  From what I can tell, the hard disk no longer has any such partitions.

My questions are in regards to the "/" root fs partition, the (optional) "/boot" partition, the "/tmp" partition, and the "/var" partition.  In the step-by-step instructions that I read, initially it was instructed to set "/" root fs to logical. Later it was recommended to set this partition to primary for MBR schemed disks.

Given my hard disks current state, am I better off (or is it recommended) to set "/" root fs as primary or logical?  Could anyone please explain (in a way I might easily understand) the difference between primary and logical partition types? Which type(s) would I then set the "/boot", "/tmp", and "/var" partitions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every Windows system must have its own primary partition and there only can be a maximum of 4 primary + extended partitions. Not 4 each but [number of primary partitions] + [number of extended partitions] <= 4.

So put everything which isn't a Windows system partition into an extended partition.

Comment: I no longer have a Windows system on my hard disk.  Ubuntu will be my only installed operating system. This is where I am finding confusion, because I do not know what to make primary or logical.

Comment: Just make an extended partition over the entire size of your disk if it's not bigger than 2 TiB and put everything in there. If it's bigger than 2 TiB, tell me.

Comment: No, it is not bigger than 2 TiB. 

So, it is not important and/or necessary to create the other recommended partitions that I read about?

Comment: No. And to clear up your doubts, here is a screenshot of GParted showing the partitions on my laptop: http://postimg.org/image/3r5vhq5wf/ The only partitions not in the extended partition are the ones I had Windows Installer made when installing Windows.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have the computer of discussion set up to save a screen shot of what I see when I enter manual partitioning at install, but I was able to create something that gives a decent idea of what I'm dealing with:  [link](http://postimg.org/image/a3nl7vzmt/)  

So, am I understanding you correctly:  I do not need to create swap, root, home, toot, tmp, or var partitions? I tried running Ubuntu on this computer before, and ran into severe slowing down, which i contributed to a lack of storage. I was hoping to fix that.

Comment: You don't *need* any of these. You only need a system partition. However, I strongly recommend making at least a swap partition so you don't run out of ram as fast. I also recommend making a backup partition for daily backups. You see the Windows partition in the screenshot? I'm using it as backup partition for daily backups because I don't want them to be on the same FS and I don't want to plug in an external drive every day. I'm just saying that you should put everything inside an extended partition so you don't have to worry about the 4 partitions limit if you decide to make more partitions

Comment: Oh, OK! This is making far more sense to me now! Thank you for explaining yourself so thoroughly--the picture definitely helped. Am I able to increase the amount of ram available by creating a larger-sized swap partition?

Comment: If your system runs out of ram and there is a swap partition, it will be able to put unused parts of the information stored in the ram on that partition, so you effectively have more of it. However, since ram is much faster than an HDD or an SSD, the information stored there is slower to be accessed, which is why your system tries not to put frequently accessed information there. So it's not as good as ram but it's way better than nothing. ;-)

Comment: The instructions that I read prior to submitting this question made the recommendation of putting the swap partition at the beginning of the disk because it will perform slower if placed at the end. Is this accurate?

Comment: It depends. If you use an HDD, the more left you are on the strip in GParted, the more on the outside of the HDD you are. This means that per revolution more data can be read or written which makes reading and writing faster since the frequency with which the discs rotate is constant. You should put the system partition (for booting, applications, etc.) and your swap partition on the beginning and data partitions on the end of the strip (left to right). The reason you're not seeing this done in my screenshot is that I use an SSD where the speed is constant over the entire strip.

Comment: You can test this yourself by launching the application "Disks", selecting your disk, clicking on the gearwheel and selecting "Benchmark". Make sure to uncheck write benchmark if you already have information saved on the disk. Here is a screenshot of the benchmark of my SSD: http://postimg.org/image/n6u0q6axr/ As you can see, it's pretty flat. Therefore, I don't care where which partition is.

Comment: This is a bit over my head. However, I ran the application "Disks" while in a "Try Ubuntu" session. It appears that it created partitions of its own for this "Trial".  This is what the benchmark of my Serial ATA Hard Disk Drive produced:  http://postimg.org/image/mdkt5g9kh/ .  Unfortunately, I do not know what these readings mean.

Comment: After re-reading the instructions you provided, I think I better understand what the benchmark shows.  Mine tells me that I need to place my partitions as you stated for a HDD--thus the diagonal, downward direction of the benchmark results. Right? :)

Comment: Correct. And all I can see of partitions is that there is an extended partition with only a swap partition in it on the wrong end of the strip.

Comment: Yes, I noticed it was on the wrong end as well. I believe that is what happened with my initial install.  Now I know to manually partition the swap partition on the other end! Thank you for guiding me through my questions, you've been extremely helpful! :)